# What is the different between bower and gems for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, bower

as all we know **bower** has make all the things more easier to manage frontend files such as j-query,bootstrap and many others without downloading from the sources manualy. so,how about gems for rails? ruby on rails can require frontend and manage files like bower does.

I've just start to try using bower and newbie in front end development, I have a little bit knowledge about back end development especialy in ROR. I want to know how's bower works and what the advantage of it if we collaborate with ROR, we are currently developing web using ROR. we are usually install bootstrap and many others front end frameworks using gems, but we want to move and start using bower.

where is the different about bower and gems for rails? should I use bower to manage frontend files on rails development?

Comment: Do you mean the rubygem `rails`, or a gem designed to supplement Rails (not just Ruby)? Please rephrase your question and body, as it seems to be interpreted both ways. **Also**, maybe provide a scenario or what you are developing on currently, as this will refine the scope. It sounds slightly opinion-based, so ask how do their functions differ in XYZ.

Comment: **PLEASE** Edit your question with those details. People do not always read the comments, and your comment poses a different question than what you are asking. Also, **PLEASE** edit to say whether you mean the gem `rails` or gems _for_ rails.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the question is quite opinion-based, so I'll write my own as well. There are two main differences here. Firstly, bower as you laready mentioned is to handle frontend assets only - in that case anything installed with bower will not give any helper methods within your ruby code.

Example: font-awesome can be installed both ways, but gem will give you `fa_icon` view helper, which you won't have when you install it with bower.

On the other hand, not all assets are available in form of the gem and hence bower is giving you greater choise of stuff to install.

Personally, I prefer to use bower, unless I know there are some extreme advantages in using gem.

EDIT:

Apparently there is another alternative, which is a combination of gems and bower assets - rails-assets.org. It is a gem source wrapping bower components in a gem. So if you need to install `angular`, you can (apart from installing `angular-rails` gem) add this url as a source to your Gemfile and then install `rails-resource-angular`.

Answer (score 1):

Bower lets you upgrade/update web asset files like Bootstrap, jQuery etc. Bower is a program, while Gem is packaged code written for you that you can use in your Rails application.

If you want to compare Bower, you can try to compare it with Bundle. And the difference is that while Bower manages the version for web assets, Bundle is used to install, and update gems. For bundle to work successfully, you need to list the gems you want to install in your Gemfile.

For more information on Bower, you can read [this](http://dotwell.io/taking-advantage-of-bower-in-your-rails-4-app/) article.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know what Bower is and how Rails works, I'm assuming you're asking what are the pros/cons of using one or the other for your front-end dependencies.

We can take something like Bootstrap as an example. The disadvantage to using a Rails gem, such as [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) is that everytime the underlying asset (Bootstrap) is updated or changed, you must wait for the gem's authors to update the gem accordingly. If they are slow or the gem's development/maintenance is abandoned, then now you're stuck. The pro is that the authors have specifically adapted the asset to work with Rails and its implementation is usually well-documented and simple. The bootstrap gem for rails makes it pretty easy, you basically just delete sprockets directives and use SASS's import feature.

Bower, on the other hand, is not generally made with Rails in mind, and integrating whatever package my be a bit more involved. For example, if you use bower to get BS, just adding a SASS import (assuming you are grabbing the SASS version of BS) is not going to work because the SASS load path is not going to be set to look in your `bower_components/bootstrap` folder by default.

I think that if you want to incorporate bower in your Rails workflow, you really ought to take a look at the [rails-assets gem](https://rails-assets.org/). It makes the incorporation of bower much simpler. I would also take a look at [this episode from GoRails](https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-assets) about using rails-assets. The author, Chris Oliver, seems to have the opinion that this is the way to go.